# Creating an "Open with ..." shortcut to Notepad++ but the shellex is not working

Tags: windows, notepad++

I want to create a keyboard short-cut that will open a file I am on with Notepad++.

How can I do that?

It seems the installer isn't creating the shellex for me. It actually was there and I installed the "e" trial and my "Edit with Notepad++" shortcut went away. I have since uninstalled E. I have also uninstalled/reinstalled NP++ but that still didn't bring the shell integration back.

I also found a blog entry where someone said the the SCiTE editor messes this up to. But, I don't have scite installed at least it isn't on my add/remove list.

#### UPDATE:

I installed 5.6.4 and it created the short-cut menu item again. There must have been an issue with the earlier version of the installer.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell navigate to the SendTo folder

Click on the Start button
Click in the Start Search dialog box
Type -> shell:sendto

Once you are in that SendTo folder, create a shortcut as normal. Right-click, new, Shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ installs a shell-extension to open all files.

In Windows Explorer, right-click the file, and choose "Edit with Notepad++".